# How to keep TwentyTwenty.js images in center?

Tags: jquery, css, twentytwenty

I would like to use [TwentyTwenty.js](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) code for comparing images. It all works great except the images are aligned to the left side. How can I keep them in center without explicitly setting width on container?

```
<div id="beforeafter" class="twentytwenty-container">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/300/sports/2/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/300/sports/3"/>
</div>

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#beforeafter").twentytwenty();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmEYjQ

If I set fixed width on container the images are in center, but I would prefer that images aren't restricted to width, with exception that they aren't wider than screen

If I use flex centering than the handle isn't in center

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had an hard time on it too!
I spent a lot time on all CSS I could find to be related.

Finally... Here is a simple solution:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Was there.
  $("#beforeafter").twentytwenty();

  // Mesure your images and divide by 2.
  var imgWidth = $("#beforeafter img").width()/2;

  // On the container, apply a left offset of 50% (screen center) - minus half image width.
  $("#beforeafter").css({"position":"relative","left":"calc(50% - "+ imgWidth+ "px)"});
});
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VbXZRw?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at - [Container would take the whole width of the page despite of the image width](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty/issues/50).

Basically in line 48 of `jquery.twentytwenty.js` and add:

```
container.css("height", offset.h);
container.css("max-width", offset.w); // See https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty/issues/50
```